# Is the following sentence grammatically correct (street lights casting)?

Tags: phrases, sentence

"... illuminated by the lined up street lights casting soft hues against the black."

Is it necessary to add an auxiliary verb between the words 'street lights' and 'casting'?

Another question, I've read somewhere else on the Internet of the phrase 'casting soft hues against the black' and I decided to put it in my sentence as what I've grasped so far it means 'the street lights are lightning the dark, causing one color of lights in a pitch black space'. What does it actually mean in the perspective of the English native?

Thank you!

Comment: Your first quote is fine, no extra needed. But street lights 'lighten' - 'lightning' comes from the sky. I would only add a hyphen in lined-up, myself.

Comment: "street lights casting soft hues…" seems fine in or of itself. What else might matter, please?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have done 'some' internet research. I offer the following:

Your partial sentence,

> "... illuminated by the lined up street lights casting soft hues
>   against the black."

is grammatically correct. I personally would say"

> "... illuminated by the street lights casting soft hues against the
>   black of night."

No aux. verb is necessary: ie 'are casting'

As to:

> " ... what I've grasped so far it means 'the street lights are lightning the
>   dark, causing one color of lights in a pitch black space'. [And] What does
>   it actually mean in the perspective of the English native?"

change [lightning](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lightning) to [lighting](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lighting).

As to what it actually means:  street lights typically cast a white light ... into the black of night. (best I can do on this part!)

Answer (score 0):

One can use dashes to strengthen the bond between words to clarify the meaning.

"... street-lights casting ..." makes clear that 'lights' goes with 'streets', not 'casting'

One could add a relative pronoun to make clear that the street lights are doing something: "... street lights, which cast ...", albeit at the cost of the flow of the sentence

Answer (score 0):

"When the street lights go on".

•  "the end of the day and the beginning of night"

•Or "the end of light by a fall of darkness"

• "a light in the darkest hours"

•"A light "being" that brightens the darkness"
 "demonic presents",, as a reminder that the light always can shine regardless of the time

• " the start of the lightness against the darkness," 
The good vs evil 
[image]!